# Есть ли возможность получить даннные о количестве заказов любого товара на Wildberries?

Tags: python-3.x, парсер, wildberries

Пример JSON ответа с карточкой товара - https://card.wb.ru/cards/v1/detail?appType=1&curr=rub&dest=-2228342&spp=27&nm=178601980

Не нашел похожего параметра, но есть volume. Не совсем ясно что это.

Это уже больше сопутствующий вопрос. Вряд ли это объем продаж
Нашел упомнание в документации о том что это "объем товара"
[https://openapi.wb.ru/statistics/api/ru/#tag/Otchyoty/paths/~1--/get](https://openapi.wb.ru/statistics/api/ru/#tag/Otchyoty/paths/%7E1--/get)
Было предположение что это общий объем (кол-во) на всех складах для всех размеров, но у меня не сошлось (значение 'volume' и сумма stock['qty']):

```
url = 'https://card.wb.ru/cards/v1/detail?appType=1&curr=rub&dest=-2228342&spp=27&nm=178601980'
response = get_response(url)
data = response.json()
product = data['data']['products'][0]
print(product['volume'])

summ = 0
for size in product['sizes']:
    for stock in size['stocks']:
        summ += stock['qty']

print(summ)

def get_response(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    while response.status_code != 200:
        print(response.status_code)
        time.sleep(1)
        response = requests.get(url)

return response
```

Прошелся по всем XHR запросам, ничего конкретного по заказам не нашел.
Дальше начал ковырять ссылки в джава скриптах на страничке. Все что может быть похоже на выдачу информации о заказах. Пока ничего не нарыл конкретного
Есть такой эндпойнт например - https://product-order-qnt.wildberries.ru/v2/by-nm/?nm=179850439,%20179850438. Дает какую-то инфу по артикулам товаров, order quantity - что бы это значило в данном случае

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть предположения как это считают сервисы типа Маяка? Возможно отслеживают информацию об остатках? Но могут же быть еще новые поступления, их не видно в публичной выдаче API.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Судя по документации, `volume` - количество оставшегося товара, хотя я не уверен, ты получил какое-то не то json.

Исходя из документации, тебе нужен пункт "delivery_amount" -    integer Количество доставок.

Получить ты их можешь в пункте "Отчет о продажах по реализации", которые ты можешь получить под аккаунтом владельца. Поэтому по документации без аккаунта владельца никак не получишь.

Исходя из эндпойнта, приведенного тобой, `quantity` - Количество, доступное для продажи (сколько можно добавить в корзину), или Полное (непроданное) количество, которое числится за складом (= quantity + в пути) (исходя из док.API в разделе Склад).

Мое предположение таково, что при заходе на определенную карточку, он отправляет запрос и смотрит, сколько максимально товара можно купить сейчас (либо периодически с разных компов отправляет такие запросы на все карточки) и строит из этого статистику, либо сотрудничает с вб, и просит или высылать их статистику, или неограниченное количество запросов с конкретного айпи на все карточки.

[image: структура json конечно оставляет желать лучшего]